Prefect is not running on Docker Container
I'm new to docker and prefect and trying to run a basic prefect flows with docker container from my local windows.
Here is my Docker file
# We're using the latest version of Prefect with Python 3.10
FROM prefecthq/prefect:2-python3.10

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

# Add our requirements.txt file to the image and install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --trusted-host pypi.python.org --no-cache-dir

# Add our flow code to the image
COPY . /opt/prefect/flows
WORKDIR /opt/prefect/flows

ENV PREFECT_API_URL="http://127.0.0.1:4200/api"
ENV PREFECT_API_DATABASE_CONNECTION_URL="postgresql+asyncpg://prefect:prefect@host.docker.internal/prefect"

CMD python etl_flows.py && prefect server start

And below is how I build and run this docker file by CMD
docker build -t my-prefect-flow .

docker run -d --name postgres -e POSTGRES_USER=prefect -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=prefect -e POSTGRES_DB=prefect -p 5432:5432 postgres:13

docker run -p 4200:4200 --name prefect-server --link postgres my-prefect-flow

When I run in logs I could see below
___ ___ ___ ___ ___ ___ _____
| _ \ _ \ __| __| __/ __|_  _|
| _/  / _|| _|| _| (__ | |
|_| |_|_\___|_| |___\___| |_|

Configure Prefect to communicate with the server with:

  prefect config set PREFECT_API_URL=http://127.0.0.1:4200/api

View the API reference documentation at http://127.0.0.1:4200/docs

Check out the dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:4200

But when I go to http://127.0.0.1:4200
It is giving me error as
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
Here is my etl_basic flow
import prefect
from prefect import task, flow
from prefect import get_run_logger

@task
def say_hi():
    logger = get_run_logger()
    logger.info("Hello from the Health Check Flow! ")


@task
def log_platform_info():
    import platform
    import sys
    from prefect.server.api.server import SERVER_API_VERSION

    logger = get_run_logger()
    logger.info("Host's network name = %s", platform.node())
    logger.info("Python version = %s", platform.python_version())
    logger.info("Platform information (instance type) = %s ", platform.platform())
    logger.info("OS/Arch = %s/%s", sys.platform, platform.machine())
    logger.info("Prefect Version = %s ", prefect.__version__)
    logger.info("Prefect API Version = %s", SERVER_API_VERSION)


@flow(name="Health Check Flow")
def health_check_flow():
    hi = say_hi()
    log_platform_info(wait_for=[hi])


I tried to expose a different port and also with container port but the result is same.
If I try to run prefect server start directly in my local, the IP is working and UI is routing correctly it's only problem with docker

I'm not familiar with Prefect, but would it not make sense to run prefect server start first, and then your Python script, which presumably needs it to be running?

Do you need to set PREFECT_SERVER_API_HOST=0.0.0.0, as in this answer?  This seems like the symptom where a process is only listening on the container-private localhost interface and is unreachable from outside its own container.
